# emphasizing someone has definitely done something like "I did go there"

Tags: verbs, tenses

I suspect I might be wrong saying "We did were there", "I did was there".

I presume there must be infinitive form of a verb after the verb "do" of a certain tense, i.e. "We did be there", "I did be there".

Is it a common rule for this case or are there any exceptions?

Also, could you point me out to the grammar where I can find some info about this?

Comment: To use *did* you need to say something like “We did go there.” if you want to use *were* then you need to emphasize it in a different way like, “We *really* were there.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "to be" is unique in that it doesn't need "do" to do anything in simple tenses! Not to negate, not to form a question...it's a free agent!

To emphasize just use intonation/pitch: But Honey, we WERE there!

Answer (score 3):

For most verbs, *do* (and other parts *does*, *did*, *done*) are required in questions and negatives, but with an affirmative statement are optional, and normally used only for emphasis or contrast. They are *always* followed by the simple form ("infinitive") of the verb.

However, in most varieties of English, this construction is not available with "be": it is simply not grammatical to say "We did be there". As Jim says, if you need to emphasise, you have to do it in a different way.

There are some dialects of English which do allow "do" with "be"